# Rewrite boost flavored code in C++11 manner (Boost.Bind, Boost.Function)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-bind, boost-function

I have some legacy code I'd like to rewrite in C++11 style.
There are some `boost::function` defined as following

```
// void One::first(int)
boost::function<void()> a1 = boost::bind(&One::first, this, this->a); 

// void Two::second()
boost::function<void()> a2 = boost::bind(&Two::second, this); 

// void Three::third(int, const std::string &)
boost::function<void()> a3 = boost::bind(&Three::third, this, 8, str);
```

These variables are passed to function `foo` in different places:

```
foo(somearg,  a1);          
foo(anotherarg, a2);
foo(othearg, a3);
```

where `foo` is defined like following

```
void foo(const Obj &obj, boost::function<void()> caller) {
  ...
  caller();
  ...
}
```

What is the best way to rewrite this code in C++11 style?

Comment: Change the namespace from boost to std ?  (and include <functional>)

Comment: @Kiroxas: That's a good start, but perhaps not the "best" way to do this in C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, simply replace `boost` with `std`, and include the C++ header `<functional>` instead of the Boost headers. The standard `function` and `bind` are based on, and for the most part compatible with, the Boost versions.

You could make it more generic:

```
template <typename Function>
void foo(const Obj &obj, Function caller) {
    //...
    caller();
    //...
}
```

and avoid the overhead (and, as the comments point out, obscure semantic restrictions) of the `function` wrapper:

```
auto a1 = std::bind(&One::first, this, this->a); 
foo(somearg, a1);
```

You might find the lambda syntax more readable than a call to `bind`:

```
auto a1 = [this]{first(a);};
```

Comment: worth mentioning that the placeholders live in `std::placeholders` there. And there are _not_ compatible (as in interchangeable)

Comment: @sehe: Sorry, my language was a little loose, it's more accurate now. It's a bit early on a Monday for fully pedantic answers.

Comment: I felt compelled to downvote you for suggesting that `std::function` has some truly terrible overhead. It does not. The point of using a template has nothing to do with overhead.

Comment: @Puppy: I didn't say it was truly terrible; please don't put hyperbolic words into my mouth. Type erasure does have an overhead: indirection, a virtual function call or similar, and possibly memory allocation (if a small object optimisation can't be applied, as it should be in this simple case). The purpose of the template is to allow generic function types without the run-time cost of type erasure.

Comment: @Puppy: Also, if you feel compelled to downvote, I'd appreciate an explanation. If it has "nothing to do with overhead," I (and perhaps other readers) would like to learn what the purpose is, when `std::function` could do the same thing, slightly more conveniently, but with slightly more overhead.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: The purpose is to respect things like move-only functors, deleted or SFINAEd overloads, and other such semantics std::function cannot properly represent. It does have an overhead but it's really rather trivial and it would have to be a pretty exceptional case to merit moving to a template purely for performance reasons.

Comment: @puppy: Fair enough. I use templates to avoid runtime overhead rather than to enable weird semantics, but perhaps others use them for your reasons.